# Double Left and Right Buttons with angled in middle

Tags: html, css

**See this image**

[Facebook Messenger Android App Buttons  ( MESSENGER\ACTIVE )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mysYp.jpg)

**How can i achieve this ?**

in details :-

A div with 2px red border.
that div contains 2 buttons with inline block.
one is on left side and other one is at right side of DIV.
LIKE : [BUTTON1][BUTTON2]
but i want this :- [BUTTON1\BUTTON2]
a Slash style shape between both buttons.

i have tried

```css
#M_Left {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 100px solid #3fc2ff;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 400px solid #3fc2ff;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#M_Right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -40;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #3fc2ff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 400px solid #3fc2ff;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center !important;
}

.white_M {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  height: 0 !important;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 400px;
  border-width: 0 !important;
  border-style: none !important;
  color: #3fc2ff !important;
}

.M_Container {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: auto !important;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #3fc2ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="M_Container">
  <div id="M_Left"> HEY</div>
  <div id="M_Right" class="white_Mx"> </div>
</div>
```

Please help me 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create it by using following approach

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
});
```

```css
.buttonGroup {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid skyblue;
  /* Border color change as your need */
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-width: 350px;
}

button {
  flex: 1;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

button:hover:before {
  background: skyblue;
}

button:hover:after {
  background: skyblue;
}

button.current:before {
  background: skyblue;
}

button.current:after {
  background: skyblue;
}

button:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
  left: -5px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

button:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
  right: -5px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttonGroup">
  <button>Hello</button>
  <button>Bye</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Working perfectly...
But how can i change color of right button to tomato and left button to white.

Comment: But can i switch color of both ?
like add a class to left button so left button will have blue background..
and then remove that class from left button and add to right button so right button have blue background

Comment: You have to button so you can do this.

Comment: Actually i need :- 
When i click on button 1 then button1 have blue color.
and When click on Button2 then Button2 have blue color.
Like ACTIVE Button.

Comment: Okay let me check with this by css by using hover

Comment: .change button{
background: skyblue;
}
.change:before{
background: white;
z-index: 1;
}
.
.
add this in CSS and add change class in div 
but text of Button1 is not visible due to "z-index 1"

Comment: i can't able to UPVOTE your answer because i have only 15 reputation.

Comment: I updated my answer it will works as your expectation. okay happy to help you @ShubhamPanchal.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('button').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 2px solid navy;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
  cursor:pointer;
}

button:after,
button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
}

button:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
}

button.active {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

button.active:after,
button.active:before {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <button>Button</button>
  <button class="active">Active</button>
</div>
```